# USART with stm8l

Tags: c

This is my code for using usart with stm8l. The main problem I am facing is that no matter what value I assign to the USART_DR register it always takes the value 0xff without even changing as I increment my char variable. Only the USART_SR register toggles between the values 0xc0 and 0xf0 which I suppose is correct.

```
clockinit(void) //16MHz internal clock enable
{
   CLK_SWR = 0x01;
   CLK_ICKR = 0x01;
   CLK_ECKR = 0x00;
   CLK_DIVR = 0x00;
   CLK_PCKENR1 = 0xFF;
   CLK_PCKENR2 = 0xFF;
}
usartinit(void)  //usart initialisation 
{
char X;
PC_DDR = 0x10;
PC_CR1 = 0x10;
X = USART1_SR;
X = USART1_DR;
USART1_CR1 = 0x00;
USART1_CR2 = 0x0C;
USART1_CR3 = 0x0f;
USART1_CR4 = 0x03;
USART1_CR5 = 0x00;
USART1_GTR = 0x00;
USART1_PSCR = 0x00;
USART1_BRR2 = 0x0A;
USART1_BRR1 = 0x08;
}
void main()
{
char *z = "HELLO";
clockinit();
usartinit();
val = strlen(z);
while (*z)
{
    USART1_DR = (unsigned char) *z;
    while (USART1_SR_TXE == 0);
    z++;                               
}
}
```

Comment: Well, is that register do on a) read and b) write?   Where do you read it?  You read it with your debugger? Does any data get transmitted on theoutput pin when you scope it?  Note that we cannot get usefully involved with problems that involve hardware.

Comment: yeah I read it with my debugger. Where should I check the output?

Comment: Please edit your question and fix the indention.

Comment: "I read it with my debugger" does not read the value you wrote.  The register for writing and the one for reading are 2 different pieces of hardware.  They are not the same memory cell.

Comment: @chux So where can I read the value that I write?

Comment: @ABHI You cannot - it is write-only.

Comment: @chux Should I use software like tera term , hyperterminal etc to obtain the output?

Comment: @ABHI Observing the output on another view is one way.  Also consider a [shadow register](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/86032/what-actually-is-a-shadow-register)

Comment: @chux Thanks a lot for your help I managed to get it working properly

Comment: @chux  I have not yet acquired the appropriate voting privileges :). I'm trying to interface an lcd to my stm8 now and need a little bit of help. Where should I write the data that i want to display on the lcd? Is there a register analogous to the USART_DR register?

Comment: @chux I know about the right to accept the answer but the problem is 2 more people have commented in this section so I'm not getting the 'check' sign to accept the answer . Yeah I guess it would start a new post but I thought maybe you could solve it outright:)

Comment: @ABHI I can answer it outright, but that is not what the comment section if for.  Review [When shouldn't I comment?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)  Good luck

Comment: @chux Kindly ,  do answer

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour you observe is as expected:

The `USART_DR` register is indeed *two* registers. One is used when you *write* to the memory location and takes the next character to transmit. The other one is used when *reading* from the memory location and contains the last character received.

[image: Architecture of USART_DR register]

This architecture was chosen to permit simultaneously sending and receiving from the USART and that is the reason, why you do not read back from that location what you wrote to it.

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand what you meant by "why do you not read from that location what you wrote to it".

Comment: @ABHI This answer described the reason for the behaviour you observe: if you write a value to the address USART_DR, then you really write to a different hardware register than if you read a value from address USART_DR. The last sentence is just a summary of that.

Comment: how can I rectify the problem or better still how do I access TDR and RDR separately?

Comment: @ABHI You can access TDR only for writing and RDR only for reading.

Comment: Okay but how do I do it? How can I check if the value I enter is being stored correctly? Should I check the output on Tera term , hyperterminal etc?

Comment: @ABHI Why should a store to a register fail? You can rely on it to succeed. To check, if the serial transmission works properly, you have to  listen on the serial interface anyway.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how will I listen on the serial interface

Comment: @ABHI You could either connect another interface on another device and listen there or you cross-connect rx and tx, then you can read the value back on the same device

Comment: how about Tera term or hyperterminal? Can I use them for getting the output?

Comment: @ABHI If you interface the device correctly with your PC, yes, of course

Comment: I tried it but I'm getting only glitches and not a proper output.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help I managed to get it working properly